# Execute function after getting the "XHR finished loading" message

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Noob Question. Do I get this right? 
"XHR finished loading" is displayed in the console after an XML HttpRequest is done, right? 
So if I want to execute a function after the XML HttpRequest is done, I should be able to use .ajaxComplete() like in

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(){
    console.log("complete");
});
```

So anytime a XML HttpRequest is done, "complete" should appear in the console?
I've tried this with .ajaxComplete, .ajaxSuccess and .ajaxStop but got no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So anytime a XML HttpRequest is done

No. That is a [jQuery method](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) that only applies to jQuery ajax requests (e.g. those made with `jQuery.ajax` or `jQuery.post`).

In this demo you can see it only fires the ajaxComplete callback once.

```js
const url = 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random';

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  console.log("ajaxCompleteCalled");
});

$.ajax(url).then(data => console.log("jQuery ajax done"));

fetch(url).then(response => console.log("Fetch ajax done"));

const x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET", url);
x.addEventListener("load", e => console.log("XHR ajax done"));
x.send();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

There is no equivalent for the APIs built into browsers (XMLHttpRequest or fetch). Write a wrapper function instead for them.

Comment: Wow thank you for the big effort! This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

XML HttpRequest does not have a callback called ajaxComplete();

You can check the documentation of the XML HttpRequest from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'll go through the documentation you've sent me!